# ggplot2: increasing space between categorical axis ticks with geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a geom_point plot that with a large number of categorical variables, and a `size` parameter mapped to a continuous variable. When I make the plot, the categorical variables are too close together, and the large points from within each overlap. Is there any way to give a little breathing room to the axis so that this doesn't happen?  I'm aware that an alternative solution is simply to use `scale_size_area(max_size = 3)` to narrow the range of point sizes, but I'd prefer not to do this as it makes it too difficult to tell them apart.

Here's the code:

```
plot <- ggplot(allcazfull, aes(x = Family, y = ifelse(Percentage==0,NA, Percentage), fill = Treatment, size = ifelse(Number == 0, NA,Number))) +
  facet_wrap(~ Pathogen, scales = "free_x") +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#98fb98","#f77e17","#0d5a0d","#8d0707"),.6)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    aspect.ratio = 4/1,
    strip.background = element_rect(fill="white", linetype = "blank"),
    strip.text = element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(allcazfull$Family))) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  guides(fill = FALSE, size = FALSE) +
  coord_flip()
plot
```

And here's the resulting figure:
[image: tooclose]

Comment: It may sound silly, but have you tried stretching the plot panel in RStudio horizontally?

Comment: holy moly I was not aware that this was how things worked

Comment: @TactfulCactus: and make sure when you save your plot with `ggsave`, choose the right `width`, `height` and `dpi` parameters

Comment: Try adding `position = position_dodge(width)` in `geom_point()` and tweak the width value until satisfied with the look